# Micronaut NonUniqueBeanException when attempting to run application

Tags: java, mongodb, micronaut

I am in the process of attempting to upgrade a Micronaut project from 1.3.2 to the current latest
version. I have gone ahead and used the `mn create-app` utility to generate a new skeleton project, for which I used its `build.gradle` file to help me for the migration.

I have dealt with all the dependencies and I am able to build the application properly, but when I try to run it I get the following exception:

```
Message: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient, com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]
Path Taken: new MailSenderListener([CampaignEmailRepository emailRepository],CampaignRunRepository runRepository,CampaignEmailResponseConverter converter) --> new CampaignEmailRepositoryImpl([MongoClient mongoClient])
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.context.AnnotationProcessorListener.onCreated(AnnotationProcessorListener.java:45)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1954)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:2990)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfTypeInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2865)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.streamOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:772)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.streamOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:759)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lambda$initializeContext$32(DefaultBeanContext.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1595)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:220)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:2780)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:233)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:166)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.startApplicationContext(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:326)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.AbstractMicronautExtension.beforeClass(AbstractMicronautExtension.java:226)
    at io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.MicronautJunit5Extension.beforeAll(MicronautJunit5Extension.java:61)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:192)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
```

I have tried looking into this but I honestly have no idea why this is happening. For reference this is my `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.0.0"
    id "io.micronaut.application" version '1.0.5'
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '5.7.0'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
    id "jacoco"
    id "com.sourcemuse.mongo" version "1.0.7"
}

mainClassName = "fts.marketing.Application"

version "0.1"
group "fts.marketing"

distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

micronaut {
    runtime "netty"
    testRuntime "junit5"
    processing {
        incremental true
        annotations "fts.marketing.*"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut.mongodb:micronaut-mongo-sync")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.7")
    implementation("io.micronaut.kafka:micronaut-kafka")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.9")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.5")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.5")
    implementation("org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.0")

    // LOMBOK
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16")

    //TEST DEPENDENCIES
    testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:2.3.0:test")
    testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.3.0")
    testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:2.3.0:test")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.0")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.0")

}
```

I am using Lombok (latest version) plus all what the `mn` utlity created. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably the new version now provides you with a `MongoClient`, but you're also defining one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem stemmed from this class `MongoClientFactory` that I was using to manually create and configure my `MongoClient`. This was needed in version 1.3.x in order to be able to configure Mongo codecs.

This is not needed anymore as the behavior for registering custom codecs for the Mongo sync driver has been fixed in later versions.

Simply removing this class and annotating the various codecs with `@Singleton` resolved the issue.